# Using jquery selecting radio button when the div container is click

Tags: jquery, html

I wanted to select the radio button rad1, when I click on the flip div and same way rad2 button when I click on flip2 div.
Here is the jquery code I used. problem is this code works for the first click event but If keep continuing then radio button will not be selected. What is the wrong with code?

HTML :-

```
<div id="flip" style="width:600px;">
       <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="stat" id="exprad"> 
       <label for="exprad" >Experience</label><br>
</div>
<div id="flip2" style="width:600px;>
      <input type="radio" name="rad2" value="fin-maths" id="perrad">
     <label for="perrad">Personal</label><br>
</div>
```

Jquery :-

```
<script > 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){//when click on flip radio button
        $('input:radio[name=rad1]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true);
        $('input:radio[name=rad2]').attr('checked',false);
        });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip2").click(function(){

        $('input:radio[name=rad2]:nth(1)').attr('checked',true);//select radio button second
        $('input:radio[name=rad1]').attr('checked',false);//deselect radioi button first


        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Edited code

```
 <script > 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip").click(function(){//when click on flip radio button
            $('input:radio[name=rad1]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true);
            $('input:radio[name=rad2]').attr('checked',false);
            });
       });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#flip2").click(function(){

            $('input:radio[name=rad2]:nth(1)').attr('checked',true);//select radio button second
            $('input:radio[name=rad1]').attr('checked',false);//deselect radioi button first

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: why two document.ready???

Comment: for what do you need `:nth()` selector?

Comment: If you're trying to do checkbox functionality, use checkboxes. Otherwise just delete the javascript, clicking the label will check the radio button.

Comment: I added it since there are two click events. does this break the coding?

Comment: I tried for radio button, I know label can do it. but thing is the radio button is contain in large div containers. therefore whereever I click , I need to select radio button

Comment: You need to explain better what you are trying to do? Is this it -> http://jsfiddle.net/L7ULc/

Comment: There are 2 syntax errors in your posted code, 2 extra `})`. As you are using `lable` and `for` attributes why attaching click handlers? Why not using similar `name` attributes for creating a radio group?  Reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single `document.ready` and get rid of the `nth`.
Also use `prop()`. You also has two extra `});` which was causing an error.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBxsY/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flip").click(function () { //when click on flip radio button
        $('input:radio[name=rad1]').prop('checked', true);
        $('input:radio[name=rad2]').prop('checked', false);
    });

    $("#flip2").click(function () {
        $('input:radio[name=rad2]').prop('checked', true); //select radio button second
        $('input:radio[name=rad1]').prop('checked', false); //deselect radioi button first
    });
});
```

**No javascript option**

```
<label for="exprad" style="width:600px;">
       <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="stat" id="exprad"> 
       Experience<br/>
</label>
<label for="perrad"style="width:600px;>
     <input type="radio" name="rad2" value="fin-maths" id="perrad">
     Personal<br/>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, the prop method worked perfectly. I am new to jquery and I use following tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-select-a-radio-button-with-jquery/. I think nth function doesn't work properly. Anyway thanks again to save my time ask to use one ready function.

Comment: There is just one issue with this, it creates a functionality that's already present in HTML without the need for javascript at all ?

Comment: ok but my div tag width is about 600px. I need to select radio button not only when i press them or their labels but anywhere on the div tag.

Comment: @adeneo While that is true, this general idea can apply to other situation as the OP is learning. Totally didn't need to downvote it.

Comment: @user2451588 - use a label tag instead of a div, you can style it anyway you like you know!

Answer (score 0):

Make both radio buttons have the same name. Should solve your problem. And then you also don't need any jQuery.

```
<div id="flip" style="width:600px;"><input type="radio" name="rad1" value="stat" id="exprad"> <label for="exprad" >Experience</label><br></div> 
<div id="flip2" style="width:600px;><input type="radio" name="rad1" value="fin-maths" id="perrad"><label for="perrad">Personal</label><br></div>
```

Comment: By "name" do you mean "ID"? And if you meant ID, did you mean to suggest OP should change them to classes because it's not possible to have two IDs named the same?

Comment: Your answer says "divs". Did you mean "radio inputs"? Also, could you explain how OP could do this without jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant radio buttons. And if radio buttons have the same "name" then whenever you select one, it unselects the other automatically without any javascript needed. 

It's how they work.